# Copy a lnk file using VBS

Tags: file, scripting, file-io, vbscript, windows-scripting

Here is my code

```
Const ALL_USERS_DESKTOP = &H19&
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(ALL_USERS_DESKTOP)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path
objFSO.CopyFile "\\server\folder\folder\Name of File 8.5.lnk" , objFolderItem.Path , OverwriteExisting
```

Gives me an error on last line. I'm not sure what the problem is but I think it has to do with the lnk file. If I put a bat file or a txt file, the file gets copied. The lnk gives an error.

Using VBSEdit as my editor and CScript (not WScript)

Error message is 
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
Microsoft VBScript runtime error (18, 1) : Permission denied

I know that I have access to the server and folder. I also can copy all the other non lnk files

------------- UPDATE -----

I modified the code with the following

```
Const DESKTOP = &H10&
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path
    objFSO.CopyFile "\\server\folder\folder\Name of File 8.5.lnk" , objFolderItem.Path , OverwriteExisting
```

Same thing. It says Permission denied (even to my own desktop). Using the mouse, I can create anything I want on my desktop without a password or special privs.

Comment: I use VBSEdit and it says [C:\Users\Public\Desktop
Microsoft VBScript runtime error (18, 1) : Permission denied]

Comment: But why is this only happening to .lnk files? Have you tried copying lnk files. I want the shortcut (not the original item) copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to recreate the shortcut because VBS wont copy it.

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") 
Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\shortcut.lnk") 
link.TargetPath = "C:\dir\filename.vbs"  ' the location where you store the file on the server 
link.Arguments = ""
link.Description = "Shortcut"
link.HotKey = "CTRL+L"
link.IconLocation = "C:\dir\filename.ico"
link.WindowStyle = 1
link.WorkingDirectory = "C:\dir"
link.Save
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need a trailing slash on your detination path as it refers to the folder:

```
objFSO.CopyFile "\\server\folder\folder\Name of File 8.5.lnk" , objFolderItem.Path & "\" , True
```

Without the slash, you are trying to overwrite the folder, hence permission denied.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. I'll try it out but If i didn't add any slash and wanted to copy another file like "Name of File 8.5.doc" then it copies the file with no problem. So it's weird. Have you tried this?

Comment: Perhaps you're environment is different. I've tried a simplified version. With slash it's OK, without, it fails with permission denied. Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") objFSO.CopyFile "c:\temp\test.lnk" , "c:\test\", True